# Pegar maior ID e inserir Banco

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Minha duvida é a seguinte preciso pegar a ID com maior valor e nela inserir as informações. O arquivo PHP está funcionando mas preciso que ele identifique a ID com maior VALOR e inserir nela inves de criar uma outra.

IniciarRelatorio.php :

```
<?php
 include "conexao.php";
 session_start();

 $os_id = $_POST['os_id'];
 $localizacao = $_POST['localizacao'];
 $atividade = $_POST['atividade'];
 $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
 $data = $_POST['data'];




     // Relatorio será iniciado
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO fotos (os_id, localizacao, atividade, observacao, data) VALUES(:OS_ID, :LOCALIZACAO, :ATIVIDADE, :OBSERVACAO, :DATA)";
            $stmt = $PDO -> prepare($sql_insert);

            $stmt ->bindParam(':OS_ID', $os_id);
            $stmt ->bindParam(':LOCALIZACAO', $localizacao);
            $stmt ->bindParam(':ATIVIDADE', $atividade);
            $stmt ->bindParam(':OBSERVACAO', $observacao);
            $stmt ->bindParam(':DATA', $data);

            if($stmt -> execute()) {
            $dados = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
            $retornoApp = array("RELATORIO" => "SUCESSO", "OS_ID"=>$dados['os_id'], "LOCALIZACAO"=>$dados['localizacao'], "ATIVIDADE"=>$dados['atividade'], "OBSERVACAO" =>$dados['observacao'], "DATA" =>$dados['data'] );
} else {
    $retornoApp = array("RELATORIO" => "ERRO");

 }

 echo json_encode($retornoApp);
```

?>

Comment: Pegar a id da onde? Do banco?

Comment: Isso ele daria um select e procuraria na tabela FOTOS o maior id para inserir as informações nele

Comment: Não é só dar um `ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: Mas ai coloco uma varialvel e depois para fazer o insert seria como

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer um select com order by e limitando o retorno a 1 valor.

Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT id FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Como estás usando `PDO`, para pegar o `id` ficaria +- assim o resultado:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$id = $result['id']; //CAPTURANDO O ID
```

Comment: Consegui fazendo desse jeito: 
             $stmt = $PDO->query("SELECT id FROM fotos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
             $result = $stmt->fetch();
             $id = $result['id']; //CAPTURANDO O ID
         
 
   // Relatorio será iniciado
    $sql_insert = "UPDATE fotos set os_id = '$os_id', localizacao = '$localizacao', atividade = '$atividade', observacao = '$observacao', data = '$data' where id = '$id'";
             $stmt = $PDO -> prepare($sql_insert);